# How to call another function inside join

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote a simple LINQ join as:

```
private string DecriptPassword(String Passwrd)
{
    // Here I am doing some decryption code
}

var x = from n in db.emp
       where n.id==10
       join dept on n.deptId == dept.deptId
       select new deptemptab
                  {
                      FirtstName=n.empname,
                      LastName=n.LastName,
                      Password=DecriptPassword(n.password) // Here I need to decrypt my pwd.
                  }
```

Please Help me. How can I decrypt my password during runtime?

Comment: In the first place you should not be able to decrypt your password *at all* unless you have a **really** good reason.

Comment: Please see [ask]. What doesn't work about your code? Please describe the expected and the actual behavior. Add any exceptions or compiler messages that might be helpful.

Comment: if you can "decrypt" the password then you must immediately change how your code works to make it from now on impossible to achieve that. They are hashed for a very good reason. You should use the same hashing algorithm in Core (if possible) and leave the hashes intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not translate the method into Linq-to-sql. So you should get the value first.

After that, you can loop throughout the list to descript them.

```
var x = (from n in db.emp
        join dept on n.deptId == dept.deptId
        where n.id == 10
        select new deptemptab
        {

            FirtstName = n.empname,
            LastName = n.LastName,
            Password = n.password
        }).ToList();
x.ForEach(p => p.Password = DecriptPassword(Password));
```